# Parse CSV in python where one column indicates a hierarchal parent/child structure

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I'm not sure the best way to parse CSV data where the first column is used to denote the hierarchal structure.

Here is an example the CSV data.

```
Symbol,SecurityType,Quantity,Mid,Strike,Expiration
STONK1 (2 options),--,1,21.115,--,--
STONK1 Debit Spread1,Opt Adv,1,7.255,15.00/23.00,01/20/2023 / 08/20/2021
STONK1 01/20/2023 15.00 C,Call,1,8.05,15,1/20/2023
STONK1 08/20/2021 23.00 C,Call,-1,0.795,23,8/20/2021
STONK2 (2 options),--,1,64.66,--,--
STONK2 Debit Spread1,Opt Adv,1,23.05,70.00/50.00,08/20/2021 / 01/20/2023
STONK2 01/20/2023 50.00 C,Call,1,27.05,50,1/20/2023
STONK2 08/20/2021 70.00 C,Call,-1,4,70,8/20/2021
```

The 2nd line is the parent record for lines 3, 4, and 5. The 3rd line is the parent record for lines 4 and 5. The data in the "Symbol" column can be used to evaluate the parent/child relationship.

How can I parse this data into a format where I could loop through the parent symbols, then loop through the sub elements?

Comment: Looks like you need to write a custom parsing loop that pulls in 4 lines and a time and treats each line specifically to get what you want.

Comment: just group the lines by the Symbol?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import io
import re

csv_content = """\
Symbol,SecurityType,Quantity,Mid,Strike,Expiration
STONK1 (2 options),--,1,21.115,--,--
STONK1 Debit Spread1,Opt Adv,1,7.255,15.00/23.00,01/20/2023 / 08/20/2021
STONK1 01/20/2023 15.00 C,Call,1,8.05,15,1/20/2023
STONK1 08/20/2021 23.00 C,Call,-1,0.795,23,8/20/2021
STONK2 (2 options),--,1,64.66,--,--
STONK2 Debit Spread1,Opt Adv,1,23.05,70.00/50.00,08/20/2021 / 01/20/2023
STONK2 01/20/2023 50.00 C,Call,1,27.05,50,1/20/2023
STONK2 08/20/2021 70.00 C,Call,-1,4,70,8/20/2021
"""

parents = {}  # using a dict for convenience, more structured data may be preferable

csv_file = io.StringIO(initial_value=csv_content)  # you can use a `open()` file instead
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

parent_regex = re.compile(r"([A-Z0-9]+) \((\d+) options\)")
child_regex = re.compile(r"([A-Z0-9]+) (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (\d+\.\d+) (\w)")

for line in reader:
    if line[0].startswith("Symbol"):
        continue  # skip the first line
    parent_match = parent_regex.match(line[0])
    child_match = child_regex.match(line[0])
    if parent_match:  # can use the walrus operator here in Python 3.8+
        parent_name = parent_match.group(1)
        parents[parent_name] = {"children": []}
    elif child_match:
        child_name = child_match.group(1)
        child_date = child_match.group(2)
        child_value = child_match.group(3)
        child_letter = child_match.group(4)
        parents[child_name]["children"].append({"date": child_date, "value": child_value, "letter": child_letter})
    else:
        name = line[0].split(" ")[0]
        parents[name]["dates"] = line[5]

print(parents)
```

```
{'STONK1': {'children': [{'date': '01/20/2023', 'value': '15.00', 'letter': 'C'},
                         {'date': '08/20/2021', 'value': '23.00', 'letter': 'C'}],
            'dates': '01/20/2023 / 08/20/2021'},
 'STONK2': {'children': [{'date': '01/20/2023', 'value': '50.00', 'letter': 'C'},
                         {'date': '08/20/2021', 'value': '70.00', 'letter': 'C'}],
            'dates': '08/20/2021 / 01/20/2023'}
 }
```

I'm using a regex to determine which line it is. It is simple, but if you do not trust that your input file is correct, you may prefer using a state machine to know what to expect on each line and do validation.
This solution is more tolerant to the line ordering.

Comment: Instead of parsing the first entry on the line with regex, it looks like you could extract those values as the `csv` module would return them in the 'Strike' and 'Expiration' fields. `csv.DictReader` makes accessing these fields much easier to follow, vs numeric indexing (accessing `line["Symbol"]` instead of `line[0]`). Also, `csv.DictReader` will take care of skipping over the header line, since it reads that line to make use of the names in building the dicts for each data line.

Comment: @PaulMcG indeed, I found your answer much better than mine and thus I had upvoted it already, even before you pointed it to me :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have successive records in a list that you want to process in groups, you can use `itertools.groupby`. In your case, you need a nested call to `groupby`, since you have nested groups. The actual CSV parsing can use the plain `csv` module - it is the way you iterate over the dicts returned by the `csv.DictReader` that will determine the groups. `itertools.groupby` will do the low-level iteration over the dicts, giving you the dicts in groups based on the key function used to determine groups.

```
import csv
import itertools
from io import StringIO

data = """\
Symbol,SecurityType,Quantity,Mid,Strike,Expiration
STONK1 (2 options),--,1,21.115,--,--
STONK1 Debit Spread1,Opt Adv,1,7.255,15.00/23.00,01/20/2023 / 08/20/2021
STONK1 01/20/2023 15.00 C,Call,1,8.05,15,1/20/2023
STONK1 08/20/2021 23.00 C,Call,-1,0.795,23,8/20/2021
STONK2 (2 options),--,1,64.66,--,--
STONK2 Debit Spread1,Opt Adv,1,23.05,70.00/50.00,08/20/2021 / 01/20/2023
STONK2 01/20/2023 50.00 C,Call,1,27.05,50,1/20/2023
STONK2 08/20/2021 70.00 C,Call,-1,4,70,8/20/2021
STONK2 (1 option),--,1,64.66,--,--
STONK2 Debit Spread1,Opt Adv,1,23.05,70.00/50.00,08/20/2021 / 01/20/2023
STONK2 01/20/2024 50.00 C,Call,1,27.05,50,1/20/2023
"""
# normally this would be
#   reader = csv.DictReader(open("some_file.csv"))
# but I'm using a StringIO so I don't need to have a separate file for this example
reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(data))


# group all records that have the same starting word in Symbol
def symbol_grouping_fn(rec):
    return rec["Symbol"].split()[0]


# group all records within a symbol group with a leading '--' SecurityType
# this is an example of what I call "Fuzzy Groupby", which I describe in 
# this blog post: https://thingspython.wordpress.com/2020/11/11/fuzzy-groupby-unusual-restaurant-part-ii/
cur_option = object()
def option_grouping_fn(rec):
    global cur_option
    if rec["SecurityType"] == "--":
        # start new group by assigning new object to 'cur_option'
        cur_option = object()
    return cur_option


# groupby will give you groups of records
# use a nested groupby to get records grouped by symbol, and then 
# grouped by option subgroup within those records
for symbol, recs_for_symbol in itertools.groupby(reader, symbol_grouping_fn):
    # now look for groups of options, looking for '--' as SecurityType
    for _, recs_for_option in itertools.groupby(recs_for_symbol, option_grouping_fn):
        header = next(recs_for_option)
        print(header)
        subheader = next(recs_for_option)
        print("-", subheader)
        for rec in recs_for_option:
            print("- -", rec)
```

Prints:

```
{'Symbol': 'STONK1 (2 options)', 'SecurityType': '--', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '21.115', 'Strike': '--', 'Expiration': '--'}
- {'Symbol': 'STONK1 Debit Spread1', 'SecurityType': 'Opt Adv', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '7.255', 'Strike': '15.00/23.00', 'Expiration': '01/20/2023 / 08/20/2021'}
- - {'Symbol': 'STONK1 01/20/2023 15.00 C', 'SecurityType': 'Call', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '8.05', 'Strike': '15', 'Expiration': '1/20/2023'}
- - {'Symbol': 'STONK1 08/20/2021 23.00 C', 'SecurityType': 'Call', 'Quantity': '-1', 'Mid': '0.795', 'Strike': '23', 'Expiration': '8/20/2021'}
{'Symbol': 'STONK2 (2 options)', 'SecurityType': '--', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '64.66', 'Strike': '--', 'Expiration': '--'}
- {'Symbol': 'STONK2 Debit Spread1', 'SecurityType': 'Opt Adv', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '23.05', 'Strike': '70.00/50.00', 'Expiration': '08/20/2021 / 01/20/2023'}
- - {'Symbol': 'STONK2 01/20/2023 50.00 C', 'SecurityType': 'Call', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '27.05', 'Strike': '50', 'Expiration': '1/20/2023'}
- - {'Symbol': 'STONK2 08/20/2021 70.00 C', 'SecurityType': 'Call', 'Quantity': '-1', 'Mid': '4', 'Strike': '70', 'Expiration': '8/20/2021'}
{'Symbol': 'STONK2 (1 option)', 'SecurityType': '--', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '64.66', 'Strike': '--', 'Expiration': '--'}
- {'Symbol': 'STONK2 Debit Spread1', 'SecurityType': 'Opt Adv', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '23.05', 'Strike': '70.00/50.00', 'Expiration': '08/20/2021 / 01/20/2023'}
- - {'Symbol': 'STONK2 01/20/2024 50.00 C', 'SecurityType': 'Call', 'Quantity': '1', 'Mid': '27.05', 'Strike': '50', 'Expiration': '1/20/2023'}
```